# get dynamic data of php from one page to another

Tags: php, mysql, html, video

I have a scenario where i am displaying video small in size at the right half of the page just like YouTube and other sites do below is the given code how i retrieve my video from database and it is working fine now what i want to do is that when user clicks on the title of a video a new page open and the same video will be played in large size . By clicking on title it is going on other page but don't no how to get the same video on other page .

```
$sql = "select * from media where m_type='video' limit 2";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ("Could not access DB: " . mysqli_error());

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{   
    $src=$row['video_path'];
    $path="home/video/";
    $home=$path.$src;

    echo $row['media_id'];
    echo  "<br />";
    echo "<a href='video.html'>";
    echo $row['title']; 
    echo '</a>';
    echo "<br />";
?>
<video width="250" height="180" controls>
    <source src="<?php echo $home ?>" type="video/mp4"  >
</video> 
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: So you basically need to open a new browser window and query the database for the same video ID. Paste the code where you select the video from the database and tell more about how your website is organized.

Comment: yes right brother i have added more code . media id is the id of the video .